# RSocket on Micronaut: How to host endpoints and call other endpoints

Tags: micronaut, rsocket, rsocket-java

I understand Micronaut doesn't support RSocket, yet, and a feature request has been pending since Aug 2019.

However, RSocket is not dependent on Micronaut.  I saw this tutorial on how to start up a standalone RSocket maven project: https://www.baeldung.com/rsocket

This got me thinking and I want to know if there is a way to use RSocket on Micronaut.

My requirement is simple: To host RSocket endpoints and to call other RSocket endpoints on Micronaut.

Comment: Have you tried to implement anything that have not worked? Are you asking if such a requirement can be implemented? If it is the case, then the simple answer is YES.